# Modifying the Explorer Context Menu

Tags: windows-explorer, context-menu

My Explorer context menus are filled with various goodies that I use from time to time. I want to add another option to them, and I have done so, but I'm having troubles getting it to appear in one place.

What I have tried so far can be summarized with the following `.reg` file:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\MY_EXTENSION]
@="Open Thingy Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\MY_EXTENSION\command]
@="C:\stuff\thingy.exe \"%L\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\Shell\MY_EXTENSION]
@="Open Thingy Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\Shell\MY_EXTENSION\command]
@="C:\stuff\thingy.exe \"%L\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\Shell\MY_EXTENSION]
@="Open Thingy Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\Shell\MY_EXTENSION\command]
@="C:\stuff\thingy.exe \"%L\""
```

This almost works as intended: Right-clicking on a drive from My Computer, or a sub-directory from anywhere in Windows Explorer, correctly shows the context menu option.

However... If I Right-Click in the open whitespace of my current working directory does not produce the desired option. I know this is possible, because I've seen other options populate in this menu, including the standard Windows "Open command window here" which appears in the registry keys of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\cmd` where * is `Directory|Drive|Folder`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add an item to the context menu of a folder?](http://superuser.com/questions/419238/how-do-you-add-an-item-to-the-context-menu-of-a-folder), [How to add item to right-click menu when NOT selecting a folder or file?](http://superuser.com/questions/445925/how-to-add-item-to-right-click-menu-when-not-selecting-a-folder-or-file) etc.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, right-clicking the "background" of a directory in Windows Explorer populates from the registry keys:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\Background
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\Shell\Background
```

Adding the appropriate keys to these two locations solved this issue.