# Custom command to explorer context menu (for currently browsing folder or desktop)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, context-menu

I use Command Prompt (and other programs) really often.

What i want is add them as custom command for context menu of Windows Explorer. But not for specific file extension or folder, or all extensions, but to see it when an empty area of current folder (or desktop) clicked by the user.

I think this could be done with Windows factory tools (Windows Registry), but i am not sure how exactly.

I want to make this command to **run in current directory** (path where explorer is currently opened in). I also want to add icons and titles to that menu items.

Is there any article or example of making this?

Comment: Also see: [How do you add an item to the context menu of a folder?](http://superuser.com/questions/419238/how-do-you-add-an-item-to-the-context-menu-of-a-folder)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 did you notice that i am talking about folder space context menu? HKEY_CLASS_ROOT specifies context menu commands for files (only) and that i know many years..

Comment: I wasn't sure, as that sentence is little unclear ("folder space" doesn't mean anything to me), hence why I also linked: "How do you add an item to the context menu of a folder?"

Comment: Please edit your question to better explain exactly what you are trying to do, and what (specifically) you need our help with (aim for one question per "question") ,and point out why the solutions on the marked duplicate(s) don't work for you.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 this is the correct duplicate, not the current one. Yep, i didn't find this with google, and this is the important bit. Short answer to my question: It's `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` key. Thank you

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 changed the question so i think it should be clear now.

Comment: @fixer1234, I can undo my duplicate closure, but then I won't be able to re-mark it (I only get one close per question). I'll flag a mod and ask them to switch it around.  The best part is that the "better" duplicate is actually closed as a duplicate of the second one I mentioned.. :)